# simple ajax question

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have to send mail before submitting my php page, I am submitting the page using javascript.
my mail script is in sendmails.php file. so can I send an ajax request to send mail before submitting the page using java script ? like follows

```
function submit_page()
{
//trying to run send_mail.php
..............................//ajax codes
............................
xmlhttp.open("GET","send_mail.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
.................................

if(a)
form.action = 'one.php'
else
form.action = 'two.php'
form.submit()//form submitting using javascript
}
```

Will it run the send_mail.php file in the server ?

Thank you

Comment: What is "a" ? If it is the success state of the request, you should use it in a callback, because your request is asynchronous...

Answer (score 2):

Yes but don't rely on the fact that this happens before `send()` returns. `send()` just starts a background thread which will eventually open the connection to `send_mail.php` and post the form. So it can happen that the form is submitted *before* the mail is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it - ajax requests take a certain amount of time to complete, and you're navigating away from the page immediately, which will interfere with the request.

Suggestion - do the ajax request in synchronous mode.  That way you're guaranteed it will finish before the form submits.

Comment: So all requests that came from a page are aborted when the page is left?

Comment: I believe so - I had a problem with the request being aborted on navigating away, but it also could have been because it was in an iframe.  At the very least, though, it's not safe.  There's a good chance you'll leave the page before the ajax request can even finish sending.